# Find the closest RGB color

Tags: code-golf, string, color

Input: A valid 6 HEX digit color code wihout a # prefix
Valid:

> - 000000
> - FF00FF
> - ABC123

Your job is to find to which one of these:

```
Red:   FF0000
Green: 00FF00
Blue:  0000FF
White: FFFFFF
Black: 000000
```

the input color is the closest too, in this case you try to only match it to black or white when the RGB is the same value for all 3 (the color is grey, or black or white ofc), if there is a "tie" you can pick whichever

The output is one of the aforementioned color codes.
Examples:

```
Input: FF0000, Output: FF0000
Input: F10000, Output: FF0000
Input: 22FF00, Output: 00FF00
Input: FFFF00, Output: FF0000 or 00FF00
Input: 111112, Output: 0000FF
Input: 010101, Output: 000000
Input: A0A0A0, Output: FFFFFF
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes will win!

Comment: Ah my mistake lol

Comment: Define "closest". What distance definition should be use?

Comment: You can take the RGB parts as seperate values R[FF], G[FF], B[FF] and check which RGB part of the input number has the highest value, except for grey, black and white colors. So F0F0F1 would be blue and F2F0F1 would be red since the red part of the RGB code is the greatest

Comment: @KevinCruijssen "if there is a tie you can pick whichever"

Comment: @Arnauld No; you're only allowed to pick `000000` and `FFFFFF` when the color is completely grey.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Ah, ok. I missed that part.

Comment: @LuisMendo As I read it, the function is `var masked = [color >> 16, color >> 8 & 0xff, color & 0xff]; if (masked.allEqual()) return (~color&24)>color ? Black : White; else return [Red, Green, Blue][masked.indexOf(masked.max)]`

Comment: Are we allowed to take input as a list of 3 hex values, or even better, 3 integers from 0 to 255?

Comment: Does input/output case matter?

Comment: input has to be uppercase and in the same style as shown (6 uppercase hex chars)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Why `888888`? Surely `808080` is nearer to `FFFFFF` than `000000`?

Comment: @Neil Ah, you're completely right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>32</s> <s>31</s> 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3äHDËiнžy@Di'F}6∍ë¾5∍sZk·„FFsǝ
```

Not really happy with it, so will see if I can golf it further..

When two `RGB` parts are the largest and equal, it will use the first one (i.e. `11ABAB` will result in `00FF00`). When all three parts are equal it will output `000000` when it's the range `[00,7F]` and `FFFFFF` for the range `[80,FF]`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@PASD5fD3ZkX9h7dV@ngkqnuVmv2qKP38OpD@0yBdHFU9qHtjxrmubkVH5/7/7@FAQgCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf@PDSzxcDndnXth7dF@lg0umulut2aOO3sOrD@0zBdLFUdmHtj9qmOfmVnx87v9anf9ubgZAwGVgAGJwgdhubmAKyHMDAy4LMOByMwQLGhmBVYJkgJQhCBhxGRqBaCAPRHMZGIIgl6MBCAIFHZ0cnbjcDIDQkMvNCEwZWIIgF1iFI5e5GwhyWRiAIAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
3ä                  # Split the (implicit) input into three parts
  H                 # Convert each part from Hexadecimal to a base-10 decimal
   D                # Duplicate this list
    Ëi              # If all three values are equal:
      н             #  Leave only the first item of the list
       žy@          #  Check if it's larger than or equal to 128 ("80" in hex)
          D         #  Duplicate this truthy/falsey result
           i  }     #  If the result is truthy:
            'F     '#   Push "F"
                    #  (Implicit else:)
                    #   (Take the duplicated falsey 0)
               6∍   #  Lenghten it to size 6
     ë              # Else:
      ¾5∍           #  Push 0, lenghtened to size 5: "00000"
         s          #  Swap so the duplicated list is at the top of the stack
          Z         #  Take the max (without popping)
           k        #  Take the index of this max in the list
            ·       #  Double this index
             „FFsǝ  #  Replace the "0" in "00000" at this doubled index with "FF"
                    # (And output the top of the stack implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>163 162</s> 150 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

*-12 bytes by some small tricks (thanks to HyperNeutrino for the* `"0F"[bool]`  *idea)*

```python
def f(i):m=i[:2],i[2:4],i[4:];a,b,c=(e==max(m)for e in m);return"".join("0F"[e]*2for e in([i[:2]>"7E"]*3if a&b&c else([a,b,c]if a^b^c else[a,1^a,0])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDRasMgFIbv@xQHLxotdhhbGFgs9GK@hJiRWMMciymJg@3pM09K2H8u/PiU49HHb/4Y02lZ7qGHnkamBh2tko5HK9UZl7Nyl5Z33GsatB7aHzqwfpwgQEwwsMsU8veUCHn5HGOiRBhigzvI7Qi1a78reX0j7nCKPbT7bu8hfM2B2rWxQ9l0zVMWVzctF44xtuQw53ffzmEGDbYyRpRUHCpTbyQl2tWZjYRAfjpkpBoj190aC@kmsCq3w2mzxxf936h2UPKYYso0ew4EjlcgvHxT9mW0Pw)

I was able to find a solution without turning the three hex values to integers (mainly because 'A' comes later in the ASCII table than '9', and so '9'<'A' is true). I am not really happy with some parts, but this was the shortest I could find.

Because this solution uses a different approach than the other python3 solution, I'm posting this as a seperate answer.

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me. You can remove the space at `else "00"` for -1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 94 bytes

```javascript
s=>'00FF000000FFFFFF'.substr(([r,g,b]=s.match(/../g),r+g==g+b?r<'8'?4:10:r>b?r>g&&2:b>g&&6),6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5RC4IwFIXf@xXig9twbVNCQprSi38ielDTVZiLzfr7q7mQUKJzHi7n8nHuvZbPUtfqch/WvTw1puVG8wwwVhRsVDEKEP2o9KAgPCgscHXkmtzKoT5DSggVCKtQcC7CKlc7sAX5Jo1YqrJ3zEQQxGllR4Jwgkwtey27hnRSwBb67o6PkEep58JqjkR/kTi2@w/inl@0FF@Ia/Gk@gFHVvHUZ6E5wiLrL2TZsmfW00kr8wI)

#### How?

We could convert a bitmask to upper case hexadecimal with leading zeros using:

```javascript
.slice(1).toString(16).toUpperCase()
```

But that would cost 36 bytes, and building such a bitmask is not especially cheap either.

It's significantly shorter to extract the relevant substring from `"00FF000000FFFFFF"`, using the following offsets:

```
 pattern | offset | 00FF000000FFFFFF
---------+--------+------------------
 000000  |    4   |     ^^^^^^
 FFFFFF  |   10   |           ^^^^^^
 FF0000  |    2   |   ^^^^^^
 00FF00  |    0   | ^^^^^^
 0000FF  |    6   |       ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>219</s> <s>112</s> 110 bytes

```python
def f(s):h=max([0,1,2],key=lambda i:s[i*2:][:2]);return["00"*h+"FF"+"00"*(2-h),"F0"[s[:2]<"80"]*6][s==s[:2]*3]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq7DoMgGIV3nsIwAaXJDyatpXXowhN0Iww2YiBVaxTT@vS2cL7hXHKmLfr3WO5767qiIwtVvh6aLzHABZeWv9xW983wbJsiqMUEJpU1Slp6nV1c59FgAMz8AWuNDzkTefSUYw3YLOl5wxVgy07WLHWdF1ba/eND74rHvDpVTHMYI@lIGKc1EkrprjX8hbTIJmXqSOtsIkkiEAl0hwSqIIHOl8QP)

-107 bytes by not being bad; drew a bit of inspiration from @Heitera by avoiding input integer parsing entirely.
-2 bytes thanks to @Heitera

Comment: You can at least shorten this to [193 bytes](https://tio.run/##NU/BioMwFLz7FcHTeyo2yaKCxcNe8gW9hSAL@6KhNpUY2bY/72rZnTkMM4cZZn7G8e4/tu2bLLOwYDt02vkIi3aZbI1upSlEjfYemGPOa16IQhpzHrvb1wP@bHGlZzeUfT9QdJFufY/nQHENno30ABg0N7mQDZ5OsqoyUTdNI0WFel8oX9ZNE9RYrvNMAdBZNpGHhSIMiF0naFoIUp5mNep2zKTJU6XS/D/ak3zv2X5GNxG7hJVaNofjgwXn5zUCIm5K8R2JEm@R8vCJUm8RB2TCxcHkkx/8BQ) by turning it into a true function and just define g, h once.

Comment: @Heiteira Thanks! I've already gotten it to [112 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYqxDoMgGIR3noIwAaUJ/iatpXXowhN0Iww2YiBVahTT@vS2eN9w@S43rsm/Y7ltretwR2emfD00X2qkKARY8XJr3TfDs21wULMJHJQ1Ciy7Ti4tUzREEu45HIjW5JCFwtEzDoJoScycvzdSSWL5yZq5rveFl3b7@NA7/JgWp/A4hZhoR0Mcl0QZY5vW8h@ki70AsiOt9ypyAMkig@4ygyqZQedL5gc) with a bit of inspiration from your answer.

Comment: `"0"*h*2` can be shortened to `"00"*h`, saving 1 byte. The same with `"0"*(2-h)*2`